# Why this generator function in JavaScript is stopping before any yield expression?

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
function* logGenerator() {
    console.log(0);
    console.log(1, yield);
    console.log(2, yield);
    console.log(3, yield);
}

var gen = logGenerator();
gen.next('alpha');
console.log('mark');
gen.next('beta');
```

Output:

```
0
mark
1 beta
```

but, why not:

```
0
1 alpha
mark
2 beta
```

In the line: `gen.next('alpha');`
the code only logs `'0'` and stops but does not reach the first yield expression, while the actual should have been '`0\n1` alpha'.

And 'alpha' is never logged.

Comment: thanx for help @Lloyd Nicholson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're understanding of where the generator stops is not correct. To be fair, it's one of the most confusing aspects of generators. A generator stops immediately when it hits `yield` even if that's in the middle of an expression.

So in your example:

```
console.log(0);        // logs 0
console.log(1, yield); // evaluates the parameters to console.log, sees yield and stops before running console.log
```

You never make it to the `console.log()` because it hits yield while evaluating the parameters. It will continue and finish the `log` on the next `next()`. This is why generators are often "primed" with an initial `next()` call if they are going to depend on values passed in. The first call of `next()` can't pass a value.

Here's a simpler example showing the issue:

```js
let test = "start"

function* logGenerator() {
  console.log("genertator starting")
  test = yield
}

var gen = logGenerator();
// call initial next. `val1` is lost to priming the generator
gen.next('val1');

// the generator stops before the assignment to test
// test is still "start"
console.log(test)

// only on the second call can you get a value to test
gen.next('val2');
console.log(test)
```

Comment: thanks:-) sorry for so much late response! i'm new to stackoverflow